# Selecting parts of a polyline on a map leaflet

Tags: leaflet, line, editing

Is it possible somehow to select parts of a polyline on a leaflet map?
Say, I have a star-formed polyline, and I'd like to select one peak of it (and then remove it from the polyline).

Comment: Yes, it's possible. One possible way would be via `Leaflet.draw` plugin: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw

Comment: Another nice drawing tool is [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman)